# error: -bash: cd: too many arguments

Tags: xubuntu

I'm getting an error with the following command:

```
ali@DESKTOP-L9T54OA:~$ cd /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak 
error: -bash: cd: too many arguments
```

Comment: Also, I just randomly happened to look at this question when it popped up.  I typically look at questions tagged [tag:windows-subsystem-for-linux].  Yours isn't tagged this way, but it appears to me that you are likely using WSL on Windows.  If that's the case (and I could be wrong), along with @Nmath's great advice on improving your question, please make sure to include all relevant details (and correct tags).  If it's WSL, make sure you say so (and tag it), along with the Windows version, Ubuntu version (it's almost certainly not [tag:xubuntu]), etc.  Thanks!

Comment: The space character is a *delimiter* so you've provided multiple arguments where only one is required; ie. user error.  It's likely you intend the space as part of an argument, which means you need to *escape* it or place it in *quotes* so the space is treated as an argument character.

Answer (score 3):

```
cd /mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak
```

You have a space between `c` and `system` so `cd` is failing because it is expecting one argument and not two.  There are a couple of ways to handle spaces when changing directories.

1. Quotes

   cd "/mnt/c/Users/c system/Documents/rak"
2. Escaping the space

   cd /mnt/c/Users/c\ system/Documents/rak